# Check if Session Key is set

Tags: python, django, django-sessions

I am attempting to create a relatively simple shopping cart in Django. I am storing the cart in `request.session['cart']`. Therefore, I'll need to access the data in this session when anything is added to it. However, if the session is not already set, I cannot access it without receiving an error. Is there any way to check if a session is set, so that it can be set if it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I assume that you want to check if a *key* is set in session, not if a *session* is set (don't know what the latter means). If so:

You can do:

```
if key not in request.session:
    # Set it.
```

In your case:

```
if 'cart' not in request.session:
    # Set it.
```

**EDIT**: changed the code snippet to use `key not in` rather than `not key in`. Thanks @katrielalex.

Comment: The pythonic way would be `if key not in request.session`.

Answer (score 21):

You can use the `get`-method on the session dictionary, it will not throw an error if the key doesn't exist, but return none as a default value or your custom default value:

```
cart = request.session.get('cart')
cart = request.session.get('cart', 'no cart')
```